# New PSU makes noises, but only for a few minutes

Tags: power-supply, noise

A few days ago, I bought and installed a new power supply unit, the "Be quiet! Pure Power CM BQT L8-CM-630W". Since then, a few minutes after booting the PC, it starts to make a noise, which I have recorded because I can't describe it (video "psu noise 1"). After another few minutes, the noise suddenly changes (video "psu noise 2"). At some point (maybe 10-15 minutes), it stops completely and the computer stays quiet, or at least as much as it should be, until I turn it off. To me, it does not look like the noise has anything to do with the fan.

You don't have to watch the full videos, only the sound is important:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLo2U7pFfIvgsYx5HS5gVHEoWniqCJ1HJH

Is this a common problem? Is the PSU broken or is there a different reason for the noise? I think it's very weird that it just stops at some point and then works normally.

(BTW: The PSU fan faces upwards because the chassis manual says so)

Comment: It just sounds like coil whine, it happens. Most manufacturers don't count it as a fault. As the caps heat up with usage it can go away. Mine only does it when its using a very very low amount of power.

Comment: [Check out my answer](http://superuser.com/a/976993/166737)! Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is coil whine, and it should not happen. Be quiet! will probably swap it for a new unit if you contact them.

I had a similar problem with one of their PSUs, but the shipping back to Germany was cost-prohibitive for me, so I contacted the vendor and they replaced it.